# How to change audio volume of a particular application in Linux

Tags: c, linux, opensuse, alsa, pulseaudio

I wanted to adjust volume of a particular application(Not the entire system volume) in Linux using my c code.

Please suggest how can we do this in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to know what audio system your desktop is using.

If it's PulseAudio (a popular choice, these days), then some API documentation can be found here:

http://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/

I'm not totally sure if that's the right API for your needs (controlling *other* applications) but it's a starting point, and I'm sure further surfing/googling will get you there.